# Transfer files from Linux to Windows using Connect:Direct (ndmcli)

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer

I'm trying to transfer a file from a Linux server to a Windows server, but I'm getting an error "XCPS003I".

My script is something like that:

```
ndmcli -x > log.txt << EOJ
  submit    maxdelay=unlimited    $process_name    process    snode=$remote_node
  snodeid($user,$password)
  step1    copy    from  (file=/local_path/file.pdf    pnode    sysopts=":datatype=binary:")
    to (file=D:\remote_path\file.pdf    snode    sysopts=":datatype=binary:"    disp=rpl)
  pend;
EOJ
```

I getting a RC=8, MSST=Remote COPY step error.

My remote path is OK.

I've tried to use another kind of displaying the remote_path, like: /remote_path/file.pdf. or using double back slash with no succesful results.

I hope somebody who knows C:D can help me telling me if my script is wrong or what can I do.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Unlikely that `$user` has permissions to write to `D:\remote_path\file.pdf`. If `$user` defined as a valid user within C:D?